# Parse Push notification not receiving in cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification

I was using avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin (https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) for push notification in IOS device. channel subscription and initialisation is working fine, but when on selection push in parse.com it didn't show registered devices to send push.

Anyone having idea what might be wrong?

I also tried different Plugins for push notification using parse but, in those plugins i am getting build error. like medlei-parse-push-plugin

and cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-pushnotification-parsepushnotification  in this plugin subscription of channels crashes again and again.

and taivo/parse-push-plugin,
in this parse initialisation for push is not working.

So any suggestions what plugin is to use for push notification for ios devices for cordova project using parse?

Comment: Before I take a look I just want to make sure that you're aware that Parse will be closing down in just under a year? Any apps using parse.com will stop working in January next year.

Comment: thank you for looking. yes, i know that. Thanks, regarding this question, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [UrbanAirship](https://www.urbanairship.com/products/engage/get-started) services

[doc](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/phonegap.html)

[plugin phonegap](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push)

You can:

1. Send push, messgaes, form the nice urbanairship admin
2. Target by tags(that you can assign), device type, device id etc..
3. Join actions, deep links etc..to your push
4. In-App messages
   etc..

It has been great for my app running on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If Parse Dashboard did not show your device to send push, it's most likely because the device token was never saved by either your iOS code or the plugin's iOS code. Look for a line like this `[ParsePushPlugin saveDeviceTokenToInstallation:newDeviceToken]`

It's also possible that your installation was never saved. In the Parse Dashboard, you can look at the `Installation` table under `Core` and check if that's the case. You can also check the `deviceToken` fields to see if device token was saved.

On a related note, I maintain https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin . In the past month, I've made a lot of updates and bug fixes. The issue you see should no longer be a problem.

The plugin now works for both [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) and the outgoing [parse.com](https://parse.com). Installation is now very simple. Just  `cordova add` and set a few `config.xml` tags to indicate appId and serverUrl, etc. No more mucking with Objective C, Java, or AndroidManifest.

If you have further problems, just file an issue, I'll take a look.